# latex \vec accent misplaced in jupyter markdown / mathjax

Tags: latex, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I'm a long-time latex user just learning to use jupyter notebooks.  I've noticed that whenever I try to create latex-formatted equations in a markdown cell, the vector accents (created with "\vec{...}") are badly misplaced -- they show up way to the right of the character they are supposed to be accenting.

This seems like it must be a known/solved issue (probably an issue with MathJax, which I guess is what jupyter is using to process the latex?) but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.  Indeed, searching around for an explanation/fix, I found a number of pages that explain how to create latex-formatted equations in mathjax/markdown that show (without identifying that it is a problem!) this misplacement, e.g.:

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference     (see the "\vec{x}" under accents near the bottom of the page)

http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Typesetting%20Equations.html   (see Maxwell's equations)

http://data-blog.udacity.com/posts/2016/10/latex-primer/   (see again the "\vec{x}" under accents)

Why are the vector accents mis-placed like this, and how can this be fixed?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it is just me but I do not notice any misalignment on those pages. Maybe try to add a screenshot? What about a different browser and/or computer?

Comment: Hmm, you're right, the misalignment is not present in another browser.  (I was using Safari before, but everything looks fine from Chrome.)  I was assuming the equations were rendered in such a way that they couldn't be affected by the browser, but apparently not.  Still curious what the problem is, but evidently it's a Safari problem, not a jupyter/markdown problem....

Comment: No idea why that is the case but I glad that fixed your problem. Perhaps this should be reported to safari, or to whichever software renders latex equation in safari.

Comment: Here is a GitHub thread with some discussion of this issue, for anybody who's interested:
https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1709